# Problema con api de google para generar QR

Tags: google-api, qr

Dentro de mi sistema genero siempre un código QR basado en la api de google pero desde ayer ha venido teniendo probelmas la página. No sé si ellos están bajando el servicio, limitan las consultas o los están atacando y eso está perjudicando la emisión de mis factiras.

Quisiera saber si estoy usando una versión antigua del servicio o si está obsoleto y de ser así, si podrían ayudarme a buscar una solución para imprimir un código QR creando una api parecida a la de google ya que no he encontrado librerías en php ya que mi framework es yii1.1

La url de la impresión de QR usada es :

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http://www.abc.com

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=http://www.abc.com&chs=160x160

[image: Error que arroja google]

Ayer tuve el mismo problema y de un momento a otro volvió a funcionar.

Agradezco sus comentarios

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve investigando sobre el tema y llegué a la documentación oficial de Google  que dice que la API fue dada de baja ([aquí](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes?hl=es-419)).

Ahí se menciona que ahora el soporte para gráficos de Google se encuentra en Google Charts (antes se llamaba Infographics), pero lamentablemente esta nueva versión de la API **ya no soporta QR.** [Acá](https://groups.google.com/g/google-visualization-api/c/77YEadph9JY?pli=1) encontré un grupo en el que hablan del tema.

No manejo mucho PHP, pero como alternativas encontré esta librería que quizás pueda servir: https://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

estoy con el mismo problema, desde hace 1 semana el servicio me lanza un error 502.

Nosotros lo utilizamos para generar códigos QR con un diseñador de informes "Pentaho Reports Desingner".

Lo curioso es que funciona durante unas horas.

He llegado a la conclusión que hay algún límite de peticiones.

He estado buscado sobre el tema, he encontrado una entrada en GitHub de un servicio que puede ayudarte **https://github.com/typpo/quickchart** y para generar el código QR **https://quickchart.io/qr?ecLevel=L&text=2019031931748496** o bien **https://github.com/zxing/zxing**

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Me ocurrió lo mismo y por lo que he investigado es la API de google la que está eliminada por lo que estoy utilizando este temporalmente
[https://qrcode.tec-it.com/API/QRCode?data="](https://qrcode.tec-it.com/API/QRCode?data=%22)

Justo hoy lo comencé a utilizar y me ha funcionado, espero lo mismo.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso solucione este problema recortando el arreglo en la formula, es decir solo los datos mas importantes que va a llevar el QR.

y listo me funciona sin problema.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).